# How to Loop inside Element list that requires opening each Element page and compare element title with page title ? Using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have Categories page which has list of games categories, i need to open each category and verify that this category page title is the same as in the category list then do same for each category .. 
Test Scenario should be like this:

1. Open categories page
2. List all Categories
3. For each Category get Category text then click on category
4. Get Opened Category page title
5. Compare Page title with Category text
6. Navigate back to Categories page
7. Repeat for all Categories

Here is the code, it passes for the 1st category but fails from the 2nd and give stale element exception as it requires declaration of the categories list again

How can i continue looping on the list without declaring it each time ?!

```
Categories.PageFrmBanner(By.xpath(testData.getParam("CategBannerLocator")));
            List<WebElement> CategoriesList = Categories.ElementsList(By.xpath(testData.getParam("CategoriesListLocator")), testData.getParam("TagName"));
            for(WebElement Element : CategoriesList)
            {
                String ElementText = Element.getText().toLowerCase();
                Element.click();
                Categories.WaitForElementVisibilty(By.xpath(testData.getParam("CategoryPageTitleLocator")));
                String CategoryText = driver.findElement(By.xpath(testData.getParam("CategoryPageTitleLocator"))).getText().toLowerCase();
                Categories.compareObjectValue(testCase, "", ElementText, CategoryText);
                log.info(ElementText + "Opened successfully");
                driver.navigate().back();
            }
```

Find Categories page here for reference,
 [Categories Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YYg7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each time the page is reloaded or you navigate to another page the found objects would be lost resulting in a stale element.

A better approach would be to save the text and the links in an array, and for each link to visit the page and to check the title, in this case you are using text and not objects.